# Pentadactyl launch external program without console output

Tags: linux, pentadactyl

I use some custom commands within [Pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/) which launch external programs. For example, I have mapped a command which downloads a Youtube video, converts it to MP3 and moves it to the correct folder on my HDD.

Since this often takes ~1 minute to do, I usually switch to another window on my desktop. However, as soon as the external program has finished, Pentadactyl pops up. I thought this might have been due to the console output the external program produces, but I get the same results even if I try to redirect stdio and stderr to /dev/null, or if I run the process in the background via "&".

Is it possible to prevent Pentadactyl from popping up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Pentadactyl for a long time and don't have it installed currently, but looking at their documentation:

- http://5digits.org/help/pentadactyl/various.xhtml

Excerpt:

```
:!{cmd}
Run an external command. Runs {cmd} through system() and displays its output. Any ‘!’ in {cmd} is replaced with the previous external command, so long as it is not preceded by a backslash and 'banghist' is enabled.

:sil:silent:sil[ent] {command}
Execute a command silently. Normal messages and error messages generated by the command invocation will not be displayed and will not be added to the message history.
```

If you are using `!{cmd}` now and getting the output, maybe `:sil {cmd}` would work the way you want?

Alternatively, `:verb {cmd}`:

```
:[count]verb[ose] {command}
Execute a command with 'verbose' set to [count]. If [count] is not specified then 1 is used.
```

might be a better option.

Comment: Thanks a lot, :0verb ... worked excellently. Sorry for the late reply!

Comment: Nice, glad it worked out for you!